# Extracting numbers and text from string in R

Tags: r

I have a string and would like to extract the first sets of three numbers and any three letters next to each number and then put into a vector. So this:

```
t1 <- "The string contains numbers ranging from 3-4 cm and can reach up to 5.6 m long, and sometimes can even reach 10 m."
```

t1 would become:

```
"3-4 cm", "5.6 m", "10m"
```

I have looked up various regular expression functions like grep, grepl etc., but can't find example that matches my query. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some data that people can use to play with (a toy example).

Comment: suggestions:  `gregexpr` and `regmatches` or there is the `stringi` package and its `stri_extract_all` functions.  `gsub` could be made to work, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regular expression `[0-9.-]+\\s+[a-zA-z]{1,3}` and use the `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package to extract them:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(t1, "[0-9.-]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,3}")
[[1]]
[1] "3-4 cm" "5.6 m"  "10 m"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the suggestion. I was indeed helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. However, I noticed that the code is omitting some numbers that are embedded within brackets. For instance, suppose in my previous example I add a number embedded within brackets as follows:
t1 <- "The string contains numbers ranging from 3-4 cm  or 120(–150) cm tall and can reach up to 5.6 m long, and sometimes can even reach 10 m." The code only returns {"3-4 cm" "5.6 m"  "10 m"} but leaves out the "120(–150) cm"
Any suggestion on how to additionally extract the numbers within brackets along with the ones not embedded in brackets?

Comment: Just add `()` to the character class should be fine. `stringr::str_extract_all(t1, "[-()0-9.]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,3}")` should work

Comment: I did, but it leaves out the "120(–" and only returns the "150) cm" part.

Comment: I am not sure what the character `-` between `(` and `150` is. It's not the normal minus sign. Check the encoding of your string probably? If it is a normal minus sign it will work.

Comment: The sign is not a minus sign but "En dash". Any suggestion on how to extract that?

Comment: It is a unicode character which is encoded as `\u2013`. So add this to the character class. `stringr::str_extract_all(t1, "[-()0-9.\u2013]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]{1,3}")` should work for `En dash` now.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem :)P

Answer (score 1):

Here's how this can be done with [`gregexpr()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)+[`regmatches()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html):

```
ipartRE <- '\\d+';
fpartRE <- '\\.\\d+';
numRE <- paste0(ipartRE,'(?:',fpartRE,')?');
rangeRE <- paste0(numRE,'(?:\\s*-\\s*',numRE,')?');
pat <- paste0(rangeRE,'\\s*[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\\b');
regmatches(t1,gregexpr(perl=T,pat,t1))[[1L]];
## [1] "3-4 cm" "5.6 m"  "10 m"
```

I built up the regex incrementally from component parts for human readability, but obviously you don't need to do that.

---

To match the new pattern we need to accept an alternation for the second number which takes matching parentheses around the number. I also found that the dash in `120(–150) cm` in not a normal [ASCII hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus), but is an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash), and so I added another precomputed regular expression piece called `dashRE` which matches all 3 common dash types (ASCII, en dash, and [em dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash)):

```
ipartRE <- '\\d+';
fpartRE <- '\\.\\d+';
numRE <- paste0(ipartRE,'(?:',fpartRE,')?');
dashRE <- '[—–-]';
rangeOptParenRE <- paste0(numRE,'(?:\\s*(?:',dashRE,'\\s*',numRE,'|\\(\\s*',dashRE,'\\s*',numRE,'\\s*\\)\\s*))?');
pat <- paste0(rangeOptParenRE,'\\s*[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\\b');
regmatches(t1,gregexpr(perl=T,pat,t1))[[1L]];
## [1] "3-4 cm"       "120(–150) cm" "5.6 m"        "10 m"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion which has been helpful. However, I noticed that the code is omitting some numbers that are embedded within brackets. For instance, suppose in my previous example I add a number embedded within brackets as follows:

t1 <- "The string contains numbers ranging from 3-4 cm  or 120(–150) cm tall and can reach up to 5.6 m long, and sometimes can even reach 10 m."

The code only returns {"3-4 cm" "5.6 m"  "10 m"} but leaves out the "120(–150) cm"

Any suggestion on how to additionally extract the numbers within brackets along with the ones not embedded in brackets?